# Rails 4 to 5.2 upgrade. 'SystemStackError - stack level too deep' when calling AR changed? or changes method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have upgraded my rails app from 4.2 to 5.2 and most things are working OK however in my AR models, whenever I call .changed? or .changes I get the following error (from the console):

```
changes

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6338ms (ActiveRecord: 534.4ms)

SystemStackError - stack level too deep:
```

Nothing in my model code has changed during the update and this was working great in AR 4.2.

The error message is very unhelpful when it comes to finding out what is breaking here and I am not sure how to figure out what has broken / changed.

Comment: https://www.levups.com/en/blog/2017/undocumented-dirty-attributes-activerecord-changes-rails51.html

Comment: Instead of `changed?` use `saved_changes?`

Comment: @Salil Before I save the model, using 'saved_changes' is not showing me any changes that I make to the model i.e. name = "test"; saved_changes returns '{}'

Comment: I have downgraded to rails 5.1 and this issue "goes away" - very weird, I would like to upgrade to 5.2 so going to keep digging.

Comment: Hmmm, according to the docs here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html `changed?` should still be relevant (for checking pre-save). Finding this kind of bug can be annoying... can you try in the console putting a begin/rescue around it and catching the exception so you can manually print out the stacktrace for us?